# How to Request Permission in a Viewless Activity

Tags: android, view, permissions

I have an activity which toggles a service, but has no view.

I can request permission within a view by creating a dialog, etc.
However, I cannot seem to request permission within a viewless activity. NullPointerExceptions, Runtime Errors, and so on occur.

What is the proper way to request permission when you don't have a view? Currently, the only working solution is briefly creating a view, requesting permission, then removing the view.

Comment: How about adding a `Widget` with it's visibility set to `android:visibility="gone"` in the XML? Since the `Activity` is not supposed to show any elements in it, this _might_ work. That being said, I fail to see why a _viewless_ `Activity` shouldn't be able to show the permissions dialog. Post your code for clarity.

Comment: @IceMAN interesting idea, will try it. By viewless activity, it's just a barebone activity which starts a service and exits.